# I need to append standard header contents to the top of all of my python files

Tags: python, batch-file, comments

So, I have a bunch of python files (hundreds actually) that need a comment header at the top that contains the product name, a license reference notice, copyright information and other things.  What is the best way to do this in a batch-like way?  In other words, is there a tool I can use to specify what the header will be and what directory to apply this header to along with a *.py filter or something along those lines?  By the way, all of the header info is identical for every file.

Comment: This isn't really Python-specific (unless you're looking for a Python library, rather than a shell/batch tool, to do it for you?).

Comment: Beside not only not Python-specific, it doesn't look like you've made even the slightest attempt to do it yourself.

Comment: It's not python specific, correct.  I only tagged python because I'm dealing with my python files.  martineau- I was looking for a tool or script to do this for me since I have a million other more important things to work on.  You have a problem with that?  Why should I have tried to do it myself?  Maybe you're not gainfully employed enough and have the spare time to wander into every rat hole you come across.  This board is for people that have questions in case you haven't noticed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If instead of the batch approach you would rather use python itself, a very simplified version could be written as:

```
import os, sys

def main():
    HEADER = '''# Author: Rob
# Company: MadeupOne
# Copyright Owner: Rob
'''

    filelist = []
    for path, dir, files in os.walk(sys.argv[1]):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith('.py'):
                filelist.append(path + os.sep + file)

        for filename in filelist:
            try:
                inbuffer = open(filename, 'U').readlines()
                outbuffer = [HEADER] + inbuffer

                open(filename, 'wb').writelines(outbuffer)
            except IOError:
                print 'Please check the files, there was an error when trying to open %s...' % filename
            except:
                print 'Unexpected error ocurred while processing files...'

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Just pass the directory containing the files you want to alter and it will recursively prepend HEADER to all .py files on the path.

Comment: Ha!  I should have known python would be the answer- I guess it was too obvious?  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Bash batch syntax:

```
for i in `find {DIRECTORY} -name "*.py"`; do
    cat - $i > /tmp/f.py <<EOF
{HEADER_BLOCK}
EOF
    mv /tmp/f.py $i
done
```

Comment: +1, although some additional logic may be needed if we want to preserve the shebang and/or charset specification that may be present at the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use python itself to follow a pythonic way.

To prepend or append some text to a file, use:

```
with open('filename.py','rb') as f:
    text = f.read()
    text = prependText + text
    text = text + postText
    // whatever you want to manipulate with the code text
with open('filename.py','wb') as f:
    f.write(text)
```

Since python modules usually demonstrate a tree structure, you can always use **walk** function (**os.path.walk**) to navigate to any level of depth and apply any custom logic according to path and/or filename.

Answer (score 0):

Updated above script to work with python 3 and ignore hidden folders

```
import os, sys

def main(path):
    HEADER = '''#!/usr/bin/python3

# Copyright : 2021 European Commission
# License   : 3-Clause BSD


'''

    filelist = []
    for path, dir, files in os.walk(sys.argv[1]):
        if '/.' not in path:
            for file in files:
                if file.endswith('.py'):
                    filelist.append(path + os.sep + file)
        
    for filename in filelist:
        try:
            inbuffer = open(filename, 'r').readlines()
            outbuffer = [HEADER] + inbuffer

            open(filename, 'w').writelines(outbuffer)
            print(f"Header is added to the file: '{filename}'.")
        except IOError:
            print('Please check the files, there was an error when trying to open %s...' % filename)
        except:
            print('Unexpected error ocurred while processing files...')


if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```